# fast creating a graph from a text file in c++

Tags: c++

I want to make a graph from a text file containing 36692 nodes and each line of the text contains the source and the target node of an edge of the graph. I used the igraph library to create the graph. I wrote the following code but it is too slow. how can I improve it?

```
  igraph_empty(&graph, 36692, 0);
  ifstream inputFile("Email-Enron.txt");
  string line;

  while (getline(inputFile, line))
  {
        istringstream ss(line);       
        int v1, v2;
        ss >>  v1 >> v2 ;
        igraph_add_edge(&graph, v1, v2);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the file read is the bottleneck (which you actually should profile), I'd suggest to get rid of the superfluous `stringstream` variable.

If each line contains exactly two numbers and nothing else, then reading in the numbers pairwise directly from the stream works as well, because operator `>>` treats a new line as a white space and ignores it the same way as it ignores blanks:

```
  igraph_empty(&graph, 36692, 0);
  ifstream inputFile("Email-Enron.txt");

  int v1, v2;
  while ( (inputFile >>  v1 >> v2) ) {
        igraph_add_edge(&graph, v1, v2);
  }
```

Comment: If the file contains only (2 * 36692) numbers then it is better to read the whole file into the memory buffer with 1 read operation.

Comment: thanks. but, why it gives the error: "expected a ')' "?

Comment: used `ifstream` instead of `inputFile`; see corrected answer.

Comment: @mary Because it should actually be: `inputFile >> v1 >> v2`. `ifstream` is a type, and as such you can't call non-static member functions from it